# Finding Duplicate rows in datatable in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, datatables

I have a datatable in VB.net with few columns - Number, Name , Salary.

I want to get a list/table of "Number" that has the same ID and Salary Reapeted more than once.
for example:

- Number: 1 , Name: Dan, Salary: 2000
- Number: 2 , Name: Robert, Salary: 300
- Number: 1 , Name: Shone, Salary: 2000
- Number: 3 , Name: Kelvin, Salary: 2000
- Number: 3 , Name: Arnon, Salary: 5000

For this table I will get back "1". because it has duplicate 1 with a salary of 2000.

Thanks for anyone help

Comment: GroupBy Number and Salary and see what Groups have more than one item -- Are both Number and Salary Integer Types? Or maybe Salary is Decimal? Other?

Comment: Both are int64. And I need the code to handle the datatable in VB.net

Comment: Well, we need to see what code you have that doesn't work as expected. If you don't have any, take the hint in my previous comment and post your own implementation. -- You need to reference both `System.Data` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. -- Salary should be `Decimal`.

Comment: You should also specify if you want to do this with a query, in code or, possibly, both, depending on some *states* / use-cases.

Comment: This can certainly be done in VB on a `DataTable` but it will be a little laborious. It would be easier to do in SQL against the database. Is that an option? If not, are you required to use a loop, because it would be more concise to use LINQ. LINQ basically lets you hide a loop in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I created the DataTable, then used Linq to group it by Number and salary. The Where clause only chooses groups with count greater than 1. The Select collects the Number field.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(Long))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Salary", GetType(Long))
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Dan", 2000)
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Robert", 300)
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Shone", 2000)
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Kelvin", 2000)
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Arnon", 5000)

    Dim result = From row In dt
                 Group row By NumberSalary = New With {
                     Key .Number = row.Field(Of Long)("Number"),
                     Key .Salary = row.Field(Of Long)("Salary")}
                     Into Group
                 Where Group.Count > 1
                 Select New With {
                     Key .Number = NumberSalary.Number}
    For Each r In result
        Debug.Print(r.ToString) 'Prints { Number = 1 } in the Immediate window
    Next
End Sub
```